# Nested Object Scaffold ASP.net MVC 3 VB.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, nested

I am complete beginner with ASP.net and VB.net, I created two classes one for Teams and another for Fixtures which will take in 2 teams.

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class Team
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Points() As Integer
End Class

Public Class TeamDBContext
   Inherits DbContext
   Public Property Teams() As DbSet(Of Team)
End Class

Imports System.Data.Entity

Public Class Fixture
   Public Property ID() As Integer
   Public Property Week() As Integer
   Public Property HomeTeam() As Team
   Public Property AwayTeam() As Team

End Class



Public Class FixtureDBContext
   Inherits DbContext
   Public Property Fixtures() As DbSet(Of Fixture)
End Class
```

I created a FixturesController with the read/write actions and views. However when I go to create a Fixture in my application I only see a field for Week and not field for HomeTeam or AwayTeam.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to add them manually. Brad Wilson wrote a [`nice article`](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) explaining in details how you could make the templated helpers to recursively descend in your nested models.

Also as a side remark you probably don't need 2 db contexts, one should be enough and it could contain both your Teams and Fixtures:

```
Public Class FixtureDBContext
   Inherits DbContext
   Public Property Teams() As DbSet(Of Team)
   Public Property Fixtures() As DbSet(Of Fixture)
End Class
```

Comment: There is two 2 seperate .vb files for the Fixture and Team that is why I have the db contexts twice one for each file. how should I go about creating the fixture so should I use team IDs could you show me an example?